# Cloudfoundry step up error - caused by Chef

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, chef-infra, cloud-foundry

I followed the Readme on `https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap`

It should be work fine...
but I got the error like this :

---

### [image]

Does anyone know what's going on?
I run on Ubuntu10.04 ...

Answer (score 1):

I have not encountered this problem with the latest version of VCAP, how long has it been since you updated the copy of the VCAP source on the Ubuntu instance?

Can you also post the configuration file you are using? if any.

Comment: I just git clone it two days ago..
and which configure file you want to see?
I didn't change anything since I clone it from github
I just follow the Readme and run the script ( bash << ...)

Comment: Ok, if you aren't specifying a config file, you're using the default, this is fine. Try moving to ~/cloudfoundry/vcap and doing a "git checkout ." and a "git pull" to make sure everything is line with the repo and try the setup again by running "./cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup"